# Working with PostgreSQL and Django on Google App Engine standard environment

Tags: django, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently setting up a Django app on the Google App Engine platform,  using a standard environment. Is it possible to connect to a PosgreSQL Google Cloud SQL instance?

I can connect to a MySQL instance by following this tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine). I can't get PostgreSQL to work however - is this because PostgreSQL only works on a flexible environment?

Many thanks

Comment: PostgreSQL [CAN work](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine) with App Engine Standard. Do you see any errors when connecting? What have you tried? Are you using Python 2 or 3?